# Email goes to spam folder Gmail and outlook while having 10 in mail-tester

Tags: magento, smtp, gmail, dkim

I put a lot of effort in perfectionizing my emails in Magento, in mail-tester i even have a 10. But stil the emails (also when i send a not transactional mail) go to spam in gmail and outlook.

Any idea why?

Comment: Email deliverability involves a lot of factors.

Answer (score 0):

Email deliverability involves a lot of factors so more information is needed to help you. What are all the services you use to send email out other than Magento? Do you do email marketing? Do you get good engagement with your email marketing (opens. clicks) with low bounces? What's the nature of your business and the content you send in the Magento emails and other emails you send out (e.g., marketing emails) even if through other services?

What precisely is in your Sender Policy Framework Record (SPF) record (please post exactly what's in your SPF record for sending domain)? Do you have DKIM implemented with services that send mail on your behalf? Have you implemented DMARC?

Do you send email from a dedicated or shared IP address(s)? Check hosts and IP address for blacklists at mxtoolbox and check your senderscore at senderscore.org.

Do you know if the problem is limited to Magento or do other emails sent from that domain go to spam as well? You may want to set up a test account or two with gmail and outlook.com as it will be handy to have some email addresses to send to that you've never sent to before for testing purposes.

Note: I tried to post this as a comment but it was too many characters.

Comment: I'd say ideally you'd post the full headers of emails, too, and take a look at headers of emails from other services to compare.

BTW, you may want to look up content that can trigger spam filters. Though ISP's have gotten a lot more sophisticated, "spammy" words and phrases can still affect your inbox placement, as can a high image to text ratio. The spam filters can't read words in images so they may ding you for possibly masking spammy content in images without text to balance it out.

Comment: I know this is a lot of questions but perhaps the most important is do you send highly targeted, relevant emails to people who've opted in? I ask because engagement (opens, clicks, etc.) is critical. If people ignored or otherwise didn't react well to the emails that did get to the Inbox, the likely result would be fewer subsequent emails making it to the Inbox, creating downward momentum. The good news is you can reverse this if it's been an issue.

Comment: Authentication-Results: spf=pass (sender IP is 31.186.173.214)
 smtp.mailfrom=tricotstoffen.nl; hotmail.com; dkim=pass (signature was
 verified) header.d=tricotstoffen.nl;hotmail.com; dmarc=pass action=none
 header.from=tricotstoffen.nl;
Received-SPF: Pass (protection.outlook.com: domain of tricotstoffen.nl
 designates 31.186.173.214 as permitted sender)
 receiver=protection.outlook.com; client-ip=31.186.173.214;
 helo=cloud.tricotstoffen.nl;

Comment: This seems to show your SPF and DKIM pass but it's really not enough information to help with deliverability beyond that.